# overloaded operators keeping variables updated instead of keeping the original variables

Tags: c++, arrays, class, operator-overloading

I am trying to do some arithmetic operations with arrays.  such as array [1,2,3] + [1,2,3] should return [2,4,6].  However when I tried to do the next arithmetic [1,2,3] * [1,2,3] = it returns [4,16,36] instead of [1,4,9] that I want.  It looks to me that the original array got permanently updated to the result of the first arithmetic operation.  Please help a bit deeper than conceptual support, such as providing me some alternative coding suggestions, since I am learning C++ and this has been the toughest chapter that I encountered. Thank you very much.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include<sstream>


class TwoD
{
private:
    int MaxCols;
    double* outerArray;
    double constant;

public:
    TwoD(int size)
    {
        MaxCols = size;
        outerArray = new double[MaxCols];
    }
    TwoD(int size, double constantInput)
    {
        MaxCols = size;
        outerArray = new double[MaxCols];
        for (int k = 0; k < size; k++)
            outerArray[k] = constantInput;
    }
    TwoD(const TwoD& other): MaxCols(other.MaxCols)
    {
        outerArray = new double[MaxCols];

        for (int i = 0; i < MaxCols; i++)
            outerArray[i] = other.outerArray[i];
    }
    const TwoD& operator =(const TwoD& rightSide)
    {
        if(MaxCols != rightSide.MaxCols)
        {
            delete [] outerArray;
            outerArray = new double [rightSide.MaxCols];
        }
        MaxCols = rightSide.MaxCols;

        for (int i = 0; i < MaxCols; i++)
            outerArray[i] = rightSide.outerArray[i];

        return *this;
    }
    void input(int size)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < size; k++)
                cin >> outerArray[k];
    }
    void outPut(int size)
    {
        for (int l = 0; l < size; l++)
        {
            cout << outerArray[l]<< ", ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    const TwoD operator + (const TwoD& rightSide)
    {

        for (int l = 0; l < MaxCols; l++)
        {
            outerArray[l] = outerArray[l] + rightSide.outerArray[l];
            cout << endl;
        }

        return *this;
    }
    const TwoD operator * (const TwoD& rightSide)
    {
        for (int l = 0; l < MaxCols; l++)
        {
            outerArray[l] = outerArray[l] * rightSide.outerArray[l];
            cout << endl;
        }

        return *this;
    }
    ~TwoD()
    {
        delete[] outerArray;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int size;
    double constantInput;
    cout << "Please enter a size of an array" << endl;
    cin >> size;

    TwoD example1(size);
    cout << "input example1" << endl;
    example1.input(size);
    example1.outPut(size);

    cout << "Please enter a constant to work with: "<< endl;
    cin >> constantInput;
    TwoD constant1(size, constantInput);
    constant1.outPut(size);

    cout << "polynomial + polynomial" << endl;
    TwoD result1 = example1 + example1;
    result1.outPut(size);

    cout << "polynomial * polynomial" << endl;
    TwoD result2 = example1 * example1;
    result2.outPut(size);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try debugging?

Comment: code is working fine (meaning no crash/errors).  It just returns undesired result as I described in the question.  Thanks

Comment: @UjaeKang Debugging also means stepping through the code and inspecting intermediate values, to discover why the program behaves the way it does.

Comment: Angew. Maybe I should definitely know this.

Comment: My advice is to stop what you're doing right now and learn how to debug. It's one of the top skills a programmer (regardless of programming language) **must** know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to stop modifying the original value:

```
const TwoD operator + (const TwoD& rightSide) const
//                                   add this ^^^^^
{
    // create a new object suitable to hold the result
    TwoD result(MaxCols);
    for (int l = 0; l < MaxCols; l++)
    {
        // set the values in the result
        result.outerArray[l] = outerArray[l] + rightSide.outerArray[l];
        cout << endl;
    }
    // and finally return it
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Well, it is not working with "return result;".  So I put "return *this" back in and it is still not working.  Could you at least explain to me why "const" is added at the back end of the first line?

Comment: @UjaeKang `return *this;` is still wrong. Be more specific: What does not work? And the `const` is added to mark the method itself as `const`, meaning it won't modify the left-hand side of your operation. If you have `TwoD result = lhs + rhs;` you want neither `lhs` nor `rhs` to be modified.

Comment: @UjaeKang I'd also suggest you change the return type from `const TwoD` to `TwoD`.

Comment: Sweet! I got it.  now I see your suggested code above is creating a new object and it is returning the newly created object.  Thank you so much.

Comment: @UjaeKang I like that you worked it out yourself, that's the right spirit. +1 for your question. I wish more people would take your approach in learning, good luck with your journey of becoming a programmer :)